# Sending JSON that doesnt match model to web api is working, and i dont want it to

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm having some problems. When I send JSON data that doesnt match my type-model, I dont want to instantiate the object. I know that the reason why this happens is because I've got a parameterless constructor.

```
public TypeVm()
{
    Id = Id;
    Registration = Registration;
    Card = Card;
    TypeId = TypeId;
    OwnerId = OwnerId;
    Stamp = Stamp;
}

public IHttpActionResult Post(TypeVm type)
{
    return type== null ? BadRequest() : _typeRegisterService.AddTypeRegistration(type) > 0 ? (IHttpActionResult)Ok() : BadRequest();
}
```

If the provided JSON data doesnt match the model i simply want the object to be null (which it becomes if i dont have a parameterless constructor. The problem is that i need to have parameterless constructor since i have other constructors for the model.

Anyone who can guide me on how to solve this issue?